# What is restriction of a measure to an algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Folland's Real analysis book and I saw following sentence in the Theorem 1.14:

> Let $A 
> \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be an algebra, $\mu_0$ a [premeasure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244631/the-concept-of-premeasure) on $\mathcal{A}$, and $\mathcal{M}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. There exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ whose restriction to $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu_0$ -- namely, $\mu = \mu^* | \mathcal{M}$ (where $\mu^*$ is outer measure).

What I want to ask is, what book means by saying  **There exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ whose restriction to $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu_0$**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal M$ that gives you the same value for each element of $\mathcal A$ as $\mu_0$ would give you. That's all.

Comment: $\mu$ gives the same value fore each *element* of $\mathcal A$, not subset.

Comment: yes, of course .. i've edited my answer. ty

Answer (score -1):

This means that if you define $ \mu(E) = \mu^*( E) $ for all $ E  \in  \mathcal{M} $, then $ \mu $ is a measure on $\mathcal{M}$.